# Question on cardinality of a set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, cardinals

Does anyone know the size of this set or how to figure it out:

$$ \left\{0.a_1a_2a_3\dots \colon \sum_{i=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{G_i}\in\mathbb{R}\right\},$$
where $G_i=(9-a_{(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}j)+1})\dots(9-a_{(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}j)+i})$ and if $G_i=0$, define $\frac{1}{G_i} = 0$.

e.g. for $ 0.\dot{1}21314151617181\dot{9}\dots$, $G_2=(9-2)(9-1)=78$, $G_3=(9-3)(9-1)(9-4)=685$, $G_4=(9-1)(9-5)(9-1)(9-6)=8483$ and so on.

Comment: It would help to know what type of objects are in this set that you are defining.  Is it real numbers $x \in [0,1)$? Or sequences $\{a_i\}$? And what are the assumptions about the $a_i$ values?  Then $G_i$ is really $G_i(x)$ or $G_i(\{a_k\})$?  It may be a more valuable exercise to ask the question completely and precisely than it is to be given an answer. Once the question is formulated properly it may become easy to answer.  (For example I observe that the sum will converge whenever $G_i$ is an $i$-digit number and so...)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My intention was that this is a set of real numbers and the only condition on $ a_i $ is the condition on $ G_i $. Upon reflecting I believe this question is an example of one which may be difficult to pose and solve yet relatively unfruitful, so will leave expending too much extra thought on it. Your reply is much appreciated and in future questions I will try to make my statements more well defined, or at least state where they are ill-defined.

Comment: This is not difficult to pose or solve.  I think a precise formulation would be to define for each $x \in [0,1)$ the sequence $\{a_i(x)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ that corresponds to the unique decimal expansion (that does not contain an infinite tail of 9s), so that $x = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i(x) 10^{-i}$. Then for each $x \in [0,1)$, $G_i(x)$ is defined according to the sequence $\{a_i(x)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. And so $\sum_i 1/G_i(x)<\infty$ whenever $G_i(x)$ is an $i$-digit number for all $i$, which holds for "quite many" $x \in [0,1)$, in particular whenever $\{a_i(x)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ has no 9s.